# XSS attack not working in textarea tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xss

I had earlier coded a simple chat application using PHP and AJAX. In that, once a user sends a chat, it first goes to php and from there it is saved in the database. I use AJAX on the client side to query the db at regular intervals for new messages. Those messages I eventually am showing in a .

So in my client side code, I have a recMsg variable which is I have set as

```
recMsg = recMsg + value['chattime'] + ' <@' + value['chatby'] + '> ' + value['chat'] + '\r\n';
```

where value is an array with value['chat'] having the actual chat message.

Later I am setting text area as the follows

```
$('#received').val(recMsg + $('#received').val());
```

where received is the id of the  tag. The code for textarea (when I view the source code in browser) is

```
<textarea id="received" rows="15" cols="150"></textarea>
```

Now to try out xss attack, I am entering the following as my chat

```
</textarea>
<script>
alert("Hi");
</script>
<textarea>
```

but instead of showing me an alert box, it just shows the full message in the textarea along with the tags (it does not treat any of the tags as special and just treats them as normal text to be displayed). I tried changing the javascript such recMsg was just the chat message, and also tried using .innerHTML but no success.

So my questions are
1) Is the attack failing because I am changing the value of textarea after it has been rendered?

2) Is it possible to carry out an XSS in this way. How can I change the javascript code to enable this attack?

3) Unrelated questions - when I change the DOM element using AJAX and if I view the source, I don't see any change (for example, textarea is still empty after I have received several chats). Any reason why this is the case?

Thanks for your replies

Comment: How is `$('#received')` getting set _originally_? An XSS attack may be possible here.

Comment: This is the only place I am setting $('#received'). Inistially in the html, the <textarea> is just empty.

Comment: Sounds like it should be OK then assuming the calls like `value['chattime']` is access of the  JSON object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Your attack is failing because you are setting the `value` attribute of the textarea. The browser automatically escapes the characters for you. Think that, when you write on the textarea, writing `</textarea>` does not close it. Setting the value through javascript is the same.
2. If you want this attack to succeed, you have to change `$('#received').val(recMsg + $('#received').val());` for `$('#received').html(recMsg + $('#received').html());`. This will change the `innerHTML` property of the textarea. Though I am not sure it would work correctly. You have to try it.
3. The option 'view source code' that browsers have show just what you've downloaded from the server. If you want to see live changes, you need to open their developer tools (usually pressing `F12`). You'll see an inspector with the entire DOM tree and their style attributes.

Comment: 2. If talking about pure JS, then it won't work. jQuery will unfortunately call the script due to way it parses the string and creates the nodes.

Comment: Changing it to .html worked perfectly on both chrome and firefox. This was exactly what I wanted. Just wondering, is this the only different between value and html?

Comment: No. All elements have an `innerHTML` property that consists in the HTML code inside their tags. But only some elements (form fields) have a `value` property. The way this `value` is presented on screen depends on the type of control. It can be text, it can be a date, it can be a selection or it can be nothing (in checkboxes, for example).